# MySQL Update a column with values combined from target column and another column

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mariadb, inner-join

I want to update column `user` with the last 6 characters replaced by `id` padded with zero. All keys under column `user` are in the format `^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{8}$`. For example, here's some sample data:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 3;
+----+------------+
| id | user       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | AS12491264 |
|  2 | LQ10240183 |
|  3 | MR12037108 |
+----+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The expected result is:

```
+----+------------+
| id | user       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | AS12000001 |
|  2 | LQ10000002 |
|  3 | MR12000003 |
+----+------------+
```

I worked out the following two queries but both fail:

```sql
UPDATE users AS u
SET u.user = (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(
      SUBSTRING(s.user, 0, 4),
      LPAD(s.id, 6, '0')
    )
  FROM users AS s
  WHERE s.id = u.id
);
```

```
UPDATE users AS u
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    s.id AS id,
    CONCAT(
      SUBSTRING(s.user, 0, 4),
      LPAD(s.id, 6, '0')
    ) AS data
  FROM users AS s
) AS s ON s.id = u.id
SET u.user = s.data;
```

Both fail and give this result:

```
+----+--------+
| id | user   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | 000001 |
|  2 | 000002 |
|  3 | 000003 |
+----+--------+
```

Here's the DB schema (fetched from `mysqldump`):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user` (`user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8964 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am running on MariaDB 10.1.38.

Comment: You are really over complicating that query

Comment: I strongly recommend testing expressions in a `SELECT` statement, before incorporating them into an `UPDATE`.

Comment: @spencer7593 As its name suggests, it's really a test database. I have the original `mysqldump` to restore all changes in one shell command.

Comment: It doesn't matter if its a test database. My recommendation is the same. Expressions can be tested in a `SELECT` statement, and that allows us to return the current value as well as a new value, and that can be useful as a demonstration to a colleague, when we are asking for help.

Comment: `SUBSTRING()` starts at 1, not 0.  But see Nick's Answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
UPDATE users
SET user = CONCAT(LEFT(user,4), LPAD(id, 6, '0'))
```

Output:

```
id  user
1   AS12000001
2   LQ10000002
3   MR12000003
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5aVko6CtewTEhdEWHkcb8/0)

**Update**

Should the user column have a variable length, you can replace just the last 6 characters using this query, which uses `CHAR_LENGTH` to determine the length of the string and subtracts 6 from that to determine how many characters on the left to keep. We use [`CHAR_LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) instead of [`LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) so the query still works for multi-byte character encodings.

```
UPDATE users
SET user = CONCAT(LEFT(user,CHAR_LENGTH(user)-6), LPAD(id, 6, '0'))
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5aVko6CtewTEhdEWHkcb8/5)

Comment: This satisfies a specification of "first 4 characters kept", which is not (in the general case) the same thing as "last 6 characters replaced";

Comment: @spencer7593 `"All keys under column user are in the format ^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{8}$"` which means they are 10 characters long, so keeping the first 4 is the same as replacing the last 6

Comment: @spencer7593 have added an additional query which will replace *only* the last 6 characters and is independent of length (assuming it is at least 6 characters long).

Comment: I was fine with your solution, i was really just commenting about a more accurate description of the specification,  in the more general case, when we didn't have the guarantee of a character length of 10. For the second query, the `LENGTH` function will work for most character sets, exceptions being encodings that use multiple bytes for [A-Z0-9] characters, such as `ucs2`, `utf16`, `utf32`.  For those character sets, we would want to use the `CHAR_LENGTH` function (which operates on characters), rather than the `LENGTH` function (which operates on bytes).

Comment: @spencer7593 no problem at all you made a valid point; the answer is better for it. And thanks for the `CHAR_LENGTH` comment too, I've updated the answer with that as well (and made the demo use a multi-byte encoding)